# how to align MATRIX expressions

Tags: align, amsmath, matrices

I Have a matrix expression and I want the second term which is in the second line to be pushed a little bit to the middle here is the code :

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\begin{document}
some text
\begin{align*}
\frac {d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} \\  \phi_{qs} \\   i_{dr} \\   i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{- R_{s}}{L_{s}} &  \omega_s &\frac{ L_{m}R_{s}}{L_{s}} & 0 \\
- \omega_s     &  \frac{- R_{s}}{L_{s}} & 0 &  \frac{L_{m}R_{s}}{L_{s}} \\
\frac{L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} & \frac{-L_{m}\omega}{\sigma L_{s} 
L_{r}} & \frac{-1}{\sigma}(\frac{R_{r}}{ L_{r}}+\frac{L_{m}^2 R_{s}}{\sigma 
L_{s}^2 L_{r}}) & \frac{\omega_r}{\sigma} \\
\frac{L_{m}\omega}{\sigma L_{s} L_{r}} &\frac{L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 
L_{r}} & \frac{-\omega_r}{\sigma} & \frac{-1}{\sigma}(\frac{R_{r}}{ 
L_{r}}+\frac{L_{m}^2 R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} \\  \phi_{qs} \\   i_{dr} \\   i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}
+ \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{-L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} &  0 & \frac{1}{L_{r}} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{-L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} & 0 & \frac{1}{L_{r}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{ds} \\  V_{qs} \\   V_{dr} \\  V_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

and here is the image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I see two possibilities: adding a `phantom +` at the end of the second line, or move the `+` from the end of the first line to the beginning of the second. I also suggest, to make the matrices more readable, to use the `medium-sized` fractions from `nccmath` (~ 80% of `\displaystyle`):

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
%\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\begin{align*}
\frac {d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} \\ \phi_{qs} \\ i_{dr} \\ i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{- R_{s}}{L_{s}} & \omega_s &\mfrac{ L_{m}R_{s}}{L_{s}} & 0 \\
- \omega_s & \mfrac{- R_{s}}{L_{s}} & 0 & \mfrac{L_{m}R_{s}}{L_{s}} \\
\mfrac{L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} & \mfrac{-L_{m}\omega}{\sigma L_{s}
L_{r}} & \mfrac{-1}{\sigma}(\mfrac{R_{r}}{ L_{r}}+\mfrac{L_{m}^2 R_{s}}{\sigma
L_{s}^2 L_{r}}) & \mfrac{\omega_r}{\sigma} \\
\mfrac{L_{m}\omega}{\sigma L_{s} L_{r}} &\mfrac{L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2
L_{r}} & \mfrac{-\omega_r}{\sigma} & \mfrac{-1}{\sigma}(\frac{R_{r}}{
L_{r}}+\mfrac{L_{m}^2 R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} \\ \phi_{qs} \\ i_{dr} \\ i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}
+ \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\mfrac{-L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} & 0 & \mfrac{1}{L_{r}} & 0 \\
0 & \mfrac{-L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} & 0 & \mfrac{1}{L_{r}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{ds} \\ V_{qs} \\ V_{dr} \\ V_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}\phantom{ + }
\end{align*}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{align*}
\frac {d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} \\ \phi_{qs} \\ i_{dr} \\ i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{- R_{s}}{L_{s}} & \omega_s &\mfrac{ L_{m}R_{s}}{L_{s}} & 0 \\
- \omega_s & \mfrac{- R_{s}}{L_{s}} & 0 & \mfrac{L_{m}R_{s}}{L_{s}} \\
\mfrac{L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} & \mfrac{-L_{m}\omega}{\sigma L_{s}
L_{r}} & \mfrac{-1}{\sigma}(\mfrac{R_{r}}{ L_{r}}+\mfrac{L_{m}^2 R_{s}}{\sigma
L_{s}^2 L_{r}}) & \mfrac{\omega_r}{\sigma} \\
\mfrac{L_{m}\omega}{\sigma L_{s} L_{r}} &\mfrac{L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2
L_{r}} & \mfrac{-\omega_r}{\sigma} & \mfrac{-1}{\sigma}(\frac{R_{r}}{
L_{r}}+\mfrac{L_{m}^2 R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} \\ \phi_{qs} \\ i_{dr} \\ i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
 + \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\mfrac{-L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} & 0 & \mfrac{1}{L_{r}} & 0 \\
0 & \mfrac{-L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} & 0 & \mfrac{1}{L_{r}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{ds} \\ V_{qs} \\ V_{dr} \\ V_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're using an `align*` environment, but since you're not providing any alignment points, the two rows are right-aligned. I suggest you provide `\&` alignment points related to the `=` symbol in the first row.

[image]

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
% simplified preamble:
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
some text
\begin{align*}
\frac {d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} \\  \phi_{qs} \\   i_{dr} \\   i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{- R_{s}}{L_{s}} &  \omega_s &\frac{ L_{m}R_{s}}{L_{s}} & 0 \\
- \omega_s & \frac{- R_{s}}{L_{s}} & 0 &  \frac{L_{m}R_{s}}{L_{s}} \\
\frac{L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} & \frac{-L_{m}\omega}{\sigma L_{s} 
L_{r}} & \frac{-1}{\sigma}\bigl(\frac{R_{r}}{ L_{r}}+\frac{L_{m}^2 R_{s}}{\sigma 
L_{s}^2 L_{r}}\bigr) & \frac{\omega_r}{\sigma} \\
\frac{L_{m}\omega}{\sigma L_{s} L_{r}} &\frac{L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2  L_{r}} & 
\frac{-\omega_r}{\sigma} & \frac{-1}{\sigma} \bigl(\frac{R_{r}}{L_{r}} +\frac{L_{m}^2 R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}}\bigr)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} \\  \phi_{qs} \\   i_{dr} \\   i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&\qquad+
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{-L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} &  0 & \frac{1}{L_{r}} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{-L_{m}R_{s}}{\sigma L_{s}^2 L_{r}} & 0 & \frac{1}{L_{r}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{ds} \\  V_{qs} \\   V_{dr} \\  V_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @twimo - The best way to thank people for providing answers is not to post a thank-you note, but to upvote their answers and to "accept" the answer that best solves the typesetting concern you posted.